# Отлов http ошибок (400, 404, и т.д.) в Spring MVC

Tags: spring, mvc, java

Добрый день. Уже несколько дней бьюсь над проблемой. Хочу с помощью спринговых бинов (резолверов) отлавливать все ошибки в приложении. Отлов исключений сделал практически сразу, а вот с отловом http ошибок пока не справился.

Суть проблемы: резолвер не может перехватить http ошибки.

Не хочу использовать `web.xml` и Контроллер, ибо надеюсь что все таки есть решении с помощью контекста спринга.

Реализация отлова эксепшенов:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <map>
            ...
            <entry key="java.lang.Throwable" value=".error" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value=".error"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

ExceptionResolver, как следует из названия, занимается обработкой исключительных ситуаций.

Коды статусов HTTP (вообще говоря не все из них имеют отношение к ошибкам) вам ловить по всей видимости совершенно неоткуда, т.к. если ваше приложение является клиентом по отношению к HTTP-сервису, то ответ с любым статусом является валидным и уже ваша забота его корректно обработать. Если же ваше приложение само является HTTP-сервисом, то задача контроллера вернуть соответствующий статус код и представление, т.е. опять же ваша.

Comment: Я как бы совсем другое спрашивал :)  По сути 404,500 и тд ошибки это Exception которые срабатывают в определенных ситуациях. Т.к. резолвер не перехватывает их они доходят до веб сервера (Tomcat) который их и обрабатывает. Вот для того что бы все эксепшены не доходили до веб сервера а обрабатывались приложением мне и надо решить проблему.

Как писал выше, есть решение с контроллером, но это невалидно

Comment: Если это исключения, то чем отличается их обработка? Явно недостаточно информации.